# Trying to call a Controller method in JS in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I am having trouble while calling a Controller method from a JS method in my View. I am able to call the correct method, but the parameter is null every time I call it. I have verified that the value in the View is not null.

```
alert(vm.OrderSerial); //Returns correct string
var pdfHandlerURL = "/Delivery/DownloadFile/" + vm.OrderSerial + "/";
```

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(string orderSerial) //Always is received null
```

I have tried restructuring the pdfHandlerURL, still sends a null string or does not call method.
The vm.OrderSerial is a string in the ViewModel. I am guessing that it is a simple fix but I have not been able to figure out what it is yet. Appreciate the help!

Comment: you should remove the  `/` at the end. if that won't help add your route mapping to the question or you just might pass it as a query string `?orderSerial=`

Comment: What does your route look like? Have you tried `"/Delivery/DownloadFile?orderSerial=" + vm.OrderSerial`?

Comment: How does your routing look like? IIRC if you want to use an id as a part of URL, by default you can only use int/long, string won't work. You would need to either 1) change the type to int or long or 2) add custom routing to allow the parameter to be passed like this or 3) change the URL to include your value as a GET parameter instead, like this: ```var pdfHandlerURL = "/Delivery/DownloadFile?orderSerial=" + vm.OrderSerial;```

Comment: I was not aware that it could only handle int or long. Appreciate the help. I took the approach using ```?orderSerial=" +vm.OrderSerial;```

Comment: It can handle any type you want. You just need to set your route config/attribute appropriately.